# If $n\le |f(1/n)|\le n^{3/2}$ then prove that $f$ has a simple pole at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let, $f:\{z\in \mathbb C:0<|z|<1\}\to \mathbb C$ be analytic such that $n\le |f(1/n)|\le n^{3/2}$ for $n=2,3,...$. Assume that $z^2f(z)$ is bounded in $|z|<1$.

Show that $f$ has a pole of order $1$ at $z=0$.

***My Attempt:***

First I consider $g(z)=z^2f(z)$.  So $g$ has zero of order $2$ at $z=0$. Also $g(z)$ is analytic in $|z|<1$. Also $|g(z)|\le M$ for all $z$ in $|z|<1$. So applying Schwartz lemma ,

$|g'(0)|\le 2M$ and $|g(z)|\le M|z|^2$. Now if we can find $z_0 (\not =0)$ in $|z|<1$ such that one of these inequalities hold then we can find $g$ explicitly.....

But I could not show it...

Please help on this OR suggest any other way to solve it....

Comment: How do u get $f(0)=0$?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 But $\lim_{n\to\infty} n $ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{3/2}$ are not zero...

Comment: Dear @S.Panja-1729,I suggest you to check it again.

Comment: No,  we can't conclude $z^2f(z)$ has a zero of order $2$ at $0.$ But $z^2f(z)$  bounded implies $z^2f(z)$ has a ____ singularity at $0$, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @zhw points out, because $z^2 f$ is bounded on $0 < |z| < 1$, it has a removable discontinuity at $z=0$. Expand $z^2 f$ in a power series around zero. Now dividing by $z^2$ shows that $f$ has a pole of order at most two at zero. Now show that the condition on $n$ shows that the pole is of order at least one, and at most one.

Comment: How the condition on $n$ shows that the pole is of order at least one, and at most one?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: If $f$ has a pole of order $2$, then $f(1/n)\sim cn^2$. If $f$ has no pole, then $f(1/n)\sim c$.

Comment: @robjohn but what if $f(z)=z^{-3/2}$? is $f$ not analytic in the open punctured plane?

Comment: @vidyarthi: $f(z)=z^{-3/2}$ is *not* analytic in the punctured plane. This function requires a branch cut since circling the origin once would give us $f(z)=-f(z)$.